# TCP retransmission and one way communication (server to client only)

Tags: tcp

I'm connecting from a client written in Dart language to a TCP server written in Golang and there's this weird behavior;

After establishing a connection from client to the server, if the client sends any data, the connection freezes. I checked with Wireshark and I can see these Retransmission errors:

[Wireshark Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRkIf.png)

Also in this state the server is not able to send any thing to the client as well.

But, if the client doesn't send anything after the connection, the server is able to transmit data without any problems. Also sometimes the communication works for at last 2 packets, and this happens randomly.

Now I'm living in Iran and use ADSL2+ from the government sponsored ISP (TCI), and this problem only occurs with this provider and for my friends as well. But this is fine with 4G/LTE operators, using my sim card I can communicate to the server both ways without any problems.

Using VPN with the ADSL2+ I can as well communicate without problems.

I implemented the client in Golang to make sure the problem is not about the programming languages, I have also moved the server to another ip and tried there as well, the problem persisted.

Because of the heavy censorship on internet here, specially towards Telegram and more on ADSL services, my guess is that their system wrongly detects these packets illegal and drops them.

This doesn't happen on protocols like websocket or http, but with raw tcp which I'm using to communicate.

**How can I make sure that my problem is related to my ISP to convince them technically?**

**Notes:**

- Iran's government heavily censors content on the internet especially social network platforms like Twitter and Facebook, and messengers like Telegram and Signal.
- My application does not seem to have any problems because it **does work** on other networks like 4G/LTE and VPN. Though there might be some extra configurations that I'm not aware of.
- Using Websockets, I don't have the same problem, which I think is because of the protocol's first HTTP request. This might be giving the government the clue that its a known websocket packet.